# trying to setup multiple email domains using postfix

Tags: postfix

I have 2 domains on my ubuntu server. I am trying to figure out how to use them both on my machine using postfix. The main domain works, however the second domain has the email rejected with a "relaying denied" error. I've been told this can be fixed in postfix but apparently i'm clueless. How can i make this work?

Comment: btw i want to use unix accounts on the machine

Comment: wow thank you very much! So simple! All i needed was a comma and added the second domain. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the other domain to the `mydestination` directive in your Postfix configuration.

Comment: is there a command i need to do after that? should it be a second mydestination on the next line or a comma after the first domain?

Comment: You need to restart Postix or reload the configuration after making change, of course. Multiple domains in `mydetination` must be separated by commas.

Comment: @fkraiem: could you please [edit] your answer and put that crucial information in there?  As your answer is worded right now, it's vulnerable to automatic deletion by the system because of a lack of quality...  **;-)**

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)